# Can I resume downloading app in Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi

I started downloading a game using Wi-Fi, the game was about 1.5GB . When almost 800 MB was done I closed Wi-Fi. The download paused. Will I be able to continue from 800 MB when I connect to Wi-Fi again.  Or from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the download resumes. But in some cases the file is downloaded again.

Comment: So, that has pretty much covered the whole either/or spectrum. Is there a HOW? or a WHY? here, that I'm missing?

Comment: In several cases it ended up as error when I tried doing similar thing. Why it happened? - I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it should continue as long as you dont clear the cache.

But im not sure if it continues if you restart the phone or update the play store.